# Have the address of the client in python

Tags: python, ip, cgi

My request is : I have my web pages created in python (wherein there is html code), each pages has a button to go to the next page.
Is it possible to get the address of the client when we submit an html form for example ?
I mean, to have into the URL address of the client.

If that possible, I'll show my code, else I delete my question.

that's my **html** code :

```
ip = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])

<html>

path install: ${install_path}<br/><br/>

os: ${os}<br/><br/>

unix user: ${user_name}<br/><br/>

<form name="sd" method="get" action="ip/cgi/scriptGet.py">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/><br/>
    Pseudo: <input type="text" name="pseudo"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
```

and here my **python code**:

```
import os, sys, platform, getpass, tempfile
import webbrowser
import string
import json
import cgi, cgitb, os   

def main( server_IP,install_path):

  template = open('scriptHmtl.phtml').read()

  contenu = string.Template(template).substitute(
            install_path = install_path,
            os = user_os,
            user_name = user_login
            )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  server_IP = sys.argv[1]
  install_path = sys.argv[2]

main(server_IP,install_path)
```

Comment: How is this a Python question ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers : yes this is a python question

Comment: You didn't say nothing about python.

Comment: I execute my script in command line, it opens a web page with html form and a button, when we click on this button ti opens another page ( with localhost as URL), and I want to know if we can get client address into the URL like that http:server/cgi/script.py, sorry I have edited and added python tag .

Comment: @Rob3 : sorry I have edited and added python tag, that's is possible ?

Comment: ok, but the tip is: if you ask about something and you want to do it with any tools. It tool should be declared in the question body, not as a tag. I think it is the question of @ bruno desthuilliers and he is right.

Comment: @Rob3 : I have edited the question and the body, I'm sorry ... I'm a woman you know

Comment: @Rob3 : Thank's, because I'm blocked...

Comment: Your Python code is obviously incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cgi` and `REMOTE_ADDR` and use like this :

```
cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])
```

Put that in a variable and call the variable into action of your html form ....

Comment: Thank you, I have already made what you said, but REMOTE_ADDR is displaying also localhost ....

Comment: So, I know only that way to obtain the IP address ... sorry, may be someone whch is better than me will help you.

Comment: @Glacius: "someone" already provided all the relevant informations... But it won't help much, obviously.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers : Of course, but she's a beginner, and sometimes with beginner we must show a small example ... :)

Comment: I have edited the code (only html), I have added the ip variable and I call that variable into action, but I have always localhost....perhaps it's because I execute my scripts with my computer ...

Comment: @Glacius: have you seen how she tried to use your code sample ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers : Yes, she want to have something like I wanted few days ago...

Comment: @Glacius: your code and Katerina's one are suprisingly similar... Is this an assignment ?

Answer (score 0):

The IP of the client (which I assume is what you mean by "address of the client") is passed to your server at the TCP/IP level. If you are using CGI (which seems to be the case according to some info hidden in your comments and not stated in your question), it should be available to the CGI script environment as `REMOTE_ADDR` (cf http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875, section 4.1.8). In Python, the way to access environment variables is to use `os.environ` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ).

Note that since the CGI script will have access to this address, you don't need to add it to the URL, querystring or (in the case of a POST or PUT request) request's body.

Also note that if your server is accessed thru a proxy, load balancer or whatever, the REMOTE_ADDR might not be the real client IP and you may have to check the HTTP request's headers for a `X-Forwarded-For` header, cf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For. This header (if positionned) should be accessible in the same way as `REMOTE_ADDR` or any other request header, but possibly renamed as `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, cf http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875.txt sections  4.1 and 4.1.18.

Comment: I have added the html code ( only html form ), and I already try to get the address with REMOTE_ADDR , but it doesn't works.

Comment: You **dont** have to put it in the form's URL - the cgi script will be able to retrieve the info from it's environment, cf my answer above.

Comment: You mean the CGI script is supposed to be deployed on the client ??? Excuse me but I just don't understand WHY you're trying to do such a thing. Can you **PLEASE** explain why you're trying to add the client's IP in the URL ?

Comment: But anyway: all you need to know is in my answer. If you cannot make sense of it and update your code accordingly then what you're really asking me is doing your own job - which I'm not going to do for free.

Comment: What I want to add client's IP in the URL ? So, when we click on the button I have http://localhost:8000/cgi/scriptGet.py, but I want http:address/cgi/scriptGet.py that's all.

Comment: Are you sure you understand anything about what you're asking ?

Comment: lol yes I understand, I mean, that's what is required for un thin client, now I recover the localhost because that's the file in the server, but we the client must to access at this file.