# How to get the IP address of a client issuing a GET request to a server-side Python script

Tags: python, cgi

I have a web app that performs a GET request and submits data to a server that runs a python script and writes this data to a file.

```
import cgi
import cgitb
import os
cgitb.enable()
if cgi.FieldStorage() is not None:
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    data = form.getvalue("data")

filename = "datalog.txt"
with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(data)
```

The above code catches the GET request data and then writes it to a file.

My question is, is there a way that I am able to find out the IP address from which the request was sent? Since the data catch was done by cgi I suspect that this must almost be done by cgi.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825836/have-the-address-of-the-client-in-python/24827765#24827765

Comment: In his case, the client is coded in Python which allows REMOTE_ADDR to grab the ip of the client. In my case my python script is server side so REMOTE_ADDR just gives me the ip of my server whereas I need the ip of the client that makes the request.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In the CGI protocol, REMOTE_ADDR _is_ the IP of the client. If what you mean is that in your setup the client (posting to your CGI script) is your "web app", IOW your own server, then this web app has to forward it's own client's IP address to your script. Else please clarify your question...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you've answered my question. My web app is the client and the python script runs on the server.